# Percentage of two select statements

Tags: sql, casting, percentage

I have to get the percentage of two count statements with conditions but I can't get the decimals correct and I get two many rows. I just need one row with the percentage number.  Here is what I have.

```
SELECT (
        (
            SELECT sum(CAST(TXN AS BIGINT)) AS [TXN]
            FROM TXNTABLE1
            WHERE MONTH = '20130701' AND 
            TYPE = 'A'
        )
    /       
        (
            SELECT sum(CAST(TXN AS BIGINT)) AS [TXN]
            FROM TXNTABLE1
            WHERE MONTH = '20130701' AND 
                (
                    TYPE = 'A' OR
                    TYPE = 'B' OR
                    TYPE = 'C' OR
                    TYPE = 'D' OR
                )
            AND 
                (
                    PLANT = 'GREEN' OR
                    PLANT = 'BLUE' OR
                    PLANT = 'RED'
                )
        )
    ) *100
FROM MYTABLE
```

The TXN column is an int and it mustn't have decimals.  But the final result of the percentage should have one number past the decimal (14.1%) So I tried to CAST the SELECT statement and it I kept getting an error at the AS.

```
CAST((SELECT...FROM...WHERE) AS DECIMAL (18,2))
```

Let me know what I should do.

Comment: I'm wondering about the purpose of `MYTABLE` at the bottom, since nothing else seems to reference it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `sum(CAST(TXN AS BIGINT))` is returnin one integer so the division is cast as Integer.

Easy trick, multiply by `1.0` so the division return decimals

```
    (
        SELECT sum(CAST(TXN AS BIGINT)) AS [TXN]
        FROM TXNTABLE1
        WHERE MONTH = '20130701' AND 
        TYPE = 'A'
    ) * 1.0
    /
```